# Using OpenCV for Android in Delphi throws an error on using JList

Tags: android, opencv, delphi, firemonkey

I would like help with using OpenCV for Android (Git: https://github.com/CarlosHe/OpenCV-Android-Firemonkey), Contours example.

I don't know how can I use contours list (JList)?
I would like to loop through all the contours and output each one in a Memo1.

Here's the code (returns an error "Access violation at address C8E40F40, access address 47F027B5"):

```
    var
      LSrcMat: JMat;
      LDstMat: JMat;
      LHierarchyMat: JMat;
      LJBitmap: JBitmap;
      LThreshold: Double;
      LContoursList: JList;
      trash, maxval: Double;
      i, type_: Integer;
    begin
      FOpenCVInProgress := True;
      try
        trash := StrToFloat(edtTrash.Text);
        maxval := StrToFloat(edtMaxVal.Text);
        type_ := StrToInt(edtType.Text);
        LSrcMat := TJMat.JavaClass.init;
        LDstMat := TJMat.JavaClass.init;
        LHierarchyMat:= TJMat.JavaClass.init;
        LContoursList:= JList(TJArrayList.JavaClass.init(0));
        LJBitmap := TJBitmap.JavaClass.createBitmap(Trunc(FCamBitmap.Width), Trunc(FCamBitmap.Height), TJBitmap_Config.JavaClass.ARGB_8888);
        TJandroid_Utils.JavaClass.bitmapToMat(BitmapToJBitmap(FCamBitmap), LSrcMat);
        TJImgproc.JavaClass.cvtColor(LSrcMat, LDstMat, TJImgproc.JavaClass.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);   // change picture to gray
        LThreshold := TJImgproc.JavaClass.threshold(LDstMat, LDstMat, trash, maxval, type_);  // classify pixels into two different groups
        TJImgproc.JavaClass.Canny(LDstMat, LDstMat, LThreshold, LThreshold * 2);              // Edge detection
        TJImgproc.JavaClass.findContours(LDstMat, LContoursList, LHierarchyMat, TJImgproc.JavaClass.RETR_EXTERNAL, TJImgproc.JavaClass.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE ); // find edge
        TJImgproc.JavaClass.cvtColor(LDstMat, LDstMat, TJImgproc.JavaClass.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);   // change picture to color
        TJImgproc.JavaClass.drawContours(LDstMat, LContoursList, -1, TJScalar.JavaClass.init(255,255,0) , 3);  // draw edge
        TJandroid_Utils.JavaClass.MatToBitmap(LDstMat, LJBitmap);
        FCamBitmap := JBitmapToBitmap(LJBitmap);
 // returns an error "Access violation at address C8E40F40, access address 47F027B5"
 For i := 0 to LContoursList.size - 1 do
 begin
         Memo1.Lines.Add(JStringToString((LContoursList.get(i).toString)));
 end;
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in the debugger to see what's happening? What's the value of `Size` in the loop? What's the value of `i` when the crash occurs? How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi.
I get an error when I call LContoursList.size.

Comment: *I get an error* is absolutely useless. What **specific error** did you get? You have that information on the screen right in front of you. However, we can't see that screen from here, and that information would be very useful when trying to help you. Please provide the details that you **already have available to you** but we don't have. You're asking us for help, and it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to give you that help by giving us the information you have.

Comment: Thank you, but Dalija Prasnikar has already solved the problem

Comment: Doesn't change anything. You learned how to improve your questions in the future. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `JList` instance to pass to `findContours`, but to get the `JList` instance you cannot typecast it from `JArrayList` the way you did.

In Delphi `JList` and `JArrayList` belong to different interface hierarchies and cannot be directly typecasted. The problem is in following line

```
LContoursList:= JList(TJArrayList.JavaClass.init(0));
```

Above forced typecast will convert two incompatible interfaces without giving you any warnings and then when you try to use the `LContoursList` it will crash.

If you write the above typecast in safe manner:

```
LContoursList := TJArrayList.Create as JList;
```

you will get runtime exception, telling you that `JArrayList` does not support `JList` interface.

> Exception class EIntfCastError with message 'Interface not supported'.

Because underlying Java class supports both interfaces, you can do the typecast differently and expose underlying Java object as `JList` using following code:

```
var
  LArr: JArrayList;
  LContoursList: JList;


  LArr := TJArrayList.Create;
  LContoursList:= TJList.Wrap(LArr);
```

---

Note: In Delphi if you want to invoke default Java constructor you can merely say `TJXXX.Create` instead `TJXXX.JavaClass.init`. In your case calling Java constructor with 0 capacity does not make much difference than using default constructor.

Note: Original FMX example run is in background thread. Since you haven't shown how you are running your example, if you are using background thread, you will need to make sure that you synchronize any usage of GUI controls with the main thread.

Comment: Thank you very much Dalija! It works!! Hvala ;)